# New ParseObject not being created in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

With my App backend as parse.com, I want to have a new table in parse with my own fields. I tried creating parse object as follows:

```
ParseObject listedProperty = new ParseObject("Properties");
listedProperty.put("Intention", subIntention);
listedProperty.put("Type", subType);
listedProperty.put("City", subCity);
 listedProperty.put("Locality", subLocality);
 listedProperty.put("Address", subAdd);
   listedProperty.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.e("Yes","Success");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("No", "Unseccessfull");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

i have initialized my keys in an application class and my Login flow works well with the ParseUsers. When the above code is triggered in the on click of a button, I dont see any data or table(class) being created on parse. How can I implement this ?????????

StackTrace:

```
03-05 14:57:54.193    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:57:54.193    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa29d43c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:02.191    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:02.191    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4372fa0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:03.557    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:03.557    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2c42760, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:05.624    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:05.624    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2c05ce0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:07.495    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:07.495    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xacfc7120, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:13.677    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:13.677    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2c42340, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:18.184    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:18.184    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2c05e20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:19.784    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:19.784    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2c42a20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:21.299    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 14:58:21.299    1539-1564/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2c47e60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-05 14:58:30.897    1539-1539/com.iwillcode.realestate E/No﹕ Unseccessfull
```

Comment: have you tried implemented the callback, and check that the exception isn't null?

Comment: No, can u show me the code for that.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/SaveCallback.html take a look at the example code in the start.

Comment: I implemented the callback method, and getting "unsuccessful" in my log. So , the data is still not being created

Comment: If we are to help you further. You would have to provide the stack trace from exception e

Comment: Have you created the table "Properties" with columns "Intention", "Type", "City", etc using the parse data browser?  If not, do that first.  Hopefully you haven't yet because its your chance change your naming scheme to match conventions.

Comment: please show us the value of `e.getMessage()` so that we can help you better so we know why the exception was raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you haven't actually created the "Properties" class from the dashboard.  If you have then your issue is most likely due to the types you are passing in the `.put()` method.

For example if you have "city" column as a `String` type and you try to do

`parseObject.put("city", 1);`

it won't be successful in saving.  So make sure that all of your variables are the expected types.  Also make sure that none of the values that you try to assign are `null` as Parse doesn't allow that.